issue in promise based taskRunner
I want to create a task runner which run based on limit for eg. limit=3 i.e. run 3 task at a time, but it is not executing after given limit; below is the main code ;
what could be the issue here?


class TaskRunner {
  #limit;
  #taskQueue = [];
  #taskCount = 0;

  constructor(limit) {
    this.#limit = limit;
  }

  run(fn, id) {
    this.#taskQueue.push({ task: fn, id: id });
     this.#taskCount++;
      while(this.#taskCount <= this.#limit && this.#taskQueue.length > 0) {
        const { task, id } = this.#taskQueue.shift();
        task(id).then((p)=>{
          console.log({p});
          this.#taskCount--;
        })
      }
    console.log(this.#taskCount);
  }
}

const taskRunner = new TaskRunner(3);

const task = (arg)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("Task Completed!", arg);
      resolve(true);
    }
    , 2000)
  }
  )
}
;

taskRunner.run(task, 'id-1');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-2');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-3');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-4');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-5');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-6');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-7');



or is there any better way to handle this?

Well, you limit this to 3 tasks. So it runs 3 tasks. What should it actually do? Batch in groups of 3? Something else?

OK, so not batches of 3, just 3 slots at once. Once one finishes, the slot is taken by another, right?

yes. 3 task and if 1 finished then next task will run. 3 task run in parallel.

batch of  maximum 3  ( or whatever limit ) task should run at any given proint of time.

Well the way it's right now it will simply stop the while loop when the limit is reached. You could make it so each task, after it is done, runs a function that checks if there is anything left in the queue and run that.

it would be helpful if you answer too.

Please [edit] the question to make it clear wheat the question is. Right now it looks like you're asking "is there any better way" of doing something which is opinion-based and therefore off-topic.

How this is off-topic?  First my question is this is jot working as expected so can I get the answer and there might be chances that I am doing it wrong at all so asking for better and clear code.

The problem is that run() both enqueues the task and tries to run it. This fails when adding task over the limit, since it will not run - the condition for the while loop will evaluate as false, therefore any task over the limit does not run, nor does anything start it later.
Instead, adding a task to the queue and running the task should be two different steps. Once a task finishes, it should try to pull the next one from the queue. To this effect run() now adds to the queue1 and the private method takeNext() tries to run another task, if there is something to run and if there is still limit left
Here is how this can look. More verbose logging included to make it more apparent how tasks execute. Also, the tasks have a random delay, to show that the limit is observed - otherwise they all finish in batches"


class TaskRunner {
  #limit;
  #taskQueue = [];
  #taskCount = 0;

  constructor(limit) {
    this.#limit = limit;
  }

  run(fn, id) {
    this.#taskQueue.push({ task: fn, id: id });
    console.log(`task ${id} added. Task count: ${this.#taskCount}`);
    this.#takeNext();
  }
  
  #takeNext() {
    if (this.#taskQueue.length === 0) {
      console.log(`takeNext(): No tasks left in the queue. ${this.#taskCount} running. Nothing will run next.`)
      return;
    }
    if (this.#taskCount >= this.#limit){
      console.log(`takeNext(): Reached limit of runnint tasks ${this.#limit}. No new task will run until one finishes.`)
      return;
    }
      
    const { task, id } = this.#taskQueue.shift();
    this.#taskCount++;
    console.log(`takeNext(): Running task with id ${id}. Task count: ${this.#taskCount}`);
    
    task(id)
      .then((p)=>{
        console.log({p});
      })
      .finally(() => { 
        this.#taskCount--;
        this.#takeNext();
      });
  }
}

const taskRunner = new TaskRunner(3);

const task = (arg)=>{ 
  //1-4 seconds delay
  const randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("Task Completed!", arg);
      resolve(true);
    }
    , randomDelay)
  }
  )
}
;

taskRunner.run(task, 'id-1');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-2');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-3');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-4');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-5');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-6');
taskRunner.run(task, 'id-7');
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }



Important to note that there is no error handling here. Nothing is done with rejected tasks. To have at least a bit of safety, the queue operations are in the finally() to ensure they happen in every case. If rejection/errors from tasks should be responded to, there should be a .catch() that handles those.
1 ideally, the name should be different. It was left as "run" to preserve the interface as before.
